# How can I escape object while mouse is approaching to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue about **escaping object to left side every time while the mouse is approaching to it**.
I wrote a code snippet but it doesn't work very well.
How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
  CurrentMouseXPostion = event.pageX;
  CurrentMouseYPostion = event.pageY;
 
  var x = $("div").position();
  
  if(CurrentMouseXPostion - x.top == 1 && CurrentMouseYPostion - y.top == 1) {
    $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
  }        
});
```

```css
div {
  background:#98bf21;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Some questions about your JS: `CurrentMouse...` are not classes or constants, why are they capitalised? Also, they seem to be missing `var`/`let`/`const`. Also, why are you calling the div's position `x`? It's far more than just the x coordinate. You're also referencing `y.top`, but you never build a `y`...

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `x.left` and `x.top`. However your condition is off; in order for both differences to be exactly 1, the mouse needs to be positioned at a specific pixel. You'll probably want `< 0` or something similar instead.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Where can I fix ?

Comment: @Chris G Where can I fix ?

Comment: In your code. Your knowledge of your code, plus the comments you received, should be enough for you to know what to change, and where. If not, then it seems highly unlikely you wrote this code to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find the position and size of your div, and toggle a class on it:

```js
var $div = $("div"),
    rect = $div.get(0).getBoundingClientRect(),
    threshold = 10; // Start reacting 10px away from the div

$(document).mousemove(function(event){
  var mouseX = event.pageX,
      mouseY = event.pageY,
      hide = isBetween(mouseX, rect.x - threshold, rect.x + rect.width + threshold) &&
             isBetween(mouseY, rect.y - threshold, rect.y + rect.height + threshold);
  $div.toggleClass('hidden', hide);
});

function isBetween(n, min, max) {
  return n >= min && n <= max;
}
```

```css
div {
  background:#98bf21;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .3s ease;
}

.hidden {
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

You cannot use a condition like `==` for mouse position, because when you move your mouse, the `mousemove` event is throttled, it does not trigger on every pixel you pass over, depending on the speed you move it at.

So to trigger your `==` condition, you would need to move your mouse very slowly over that specific 1px line. Using conditions like `<` or `<=` will ensure it gets triggered.